# kafka topic with 1 partition . 1 producer is already producing to that partition. What issues can I face if i add another producer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have a topic with 1 partition.
One of the systems is acting as a producer and sending data to that partition.
I want to add another different system as producer and send data to that partition only.
What are the effects of this.
Will there be any issues related to offsets, retries or acks.
If shutdown hook is applied on one producer, will other producer be impacted? what things to take care in this?

---

If I add 1 more partition and both producer keep on producing with different keys (A for producer1, B for producer2) then will it create any problem as based on hashing , both will go to different partitions. Is this better solution and its impact on offsets and acks. And If shutdown hook is applied on one producer, will other producer be impacted?

---

On consumer side, continuing with 1st part(with both producers producing to same partition)
If consumer groups are different, there should not be any problem in consumers.

Comment: It sounds like you are new to Kafka. I suggest you to pick the free and excellent book [Kafka the definitive guide](https://www.confluent.io/resources/kafka-the-definitive-guide/), which will answer your questions. That edition of the book is a bit outdated, but will you give you the understanding **you must know** if you are going to use kafka. If you can get the 2nd edition, that will give you more up to date information.

Comment: +1 for @Augusto. Before using Kafka you should learn the basics about it. Anyways, at least for the first (and maybe the second) question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52066755/kafka-ordering-with-multiple-producers-on-same-topic-and-parititon

Answer (score 0):

1. All data arrives to the same partition. Producers are unaffected by one another.

2. Hashes aren't guaranteed to end up in different partitions; there could be a collision, which would cause the same scenario as a one partition topic, then you just have an empty second one. Again, producers are unaffected by the actions of another
3. Correct

Answer (score 0):

Multiple producers can write to a single partition without any issues. `Offsets` are managed by `Kafka` and are unique for each message, regardless of the `producer`. `Retries` and `acknowledgments` (acks) are also handled independently for each `producer`. If one producer has a shutdown hook applied, it won't impact the other `producer`.

If you add another `partition` and use distinct keys for each producer, Kafka will distribute the messages based on the key's hash. This ensures that messages with key `"A"` from `producer1` and key `"B"` from `producer2` will likely end up in different partitions. Offsets are maintained separately for each partition, and the acknowledgment mechanism remains consistent.

On the consumer side, if you have different consumer groups consuming from the same partition (where both producers are writing), there won't be any issues. Each consumer group maintains its own offset, allowing them to read messages at their own pace.

Kafka is designed to handle such scenarios seamlessly. you need to ensure that your producers and consumers are correctly configured.